# Expand within \label

Tags: cross-referencing, expansion

Is there any way to use a macro within a `\label` tag?

```
\edef\num{1}
\label{test\num}
\ref{test1}
```

Comment: Yes there is. The argument of the `\label` is written to the `.aux` file and expanded during that. You example should work. Maybe you use some packages which change `\label`? If it doesn't work for you, add a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) of your code.

Answer (score 4):

The following works as expected:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}
\def\NUM{1}
\section{X}\label{sec:\NUM}

This is section~\ref{sec:\NUM} or is it section~\ref{sec:1}?
\end{document}
```

If I load hyperref it works the same. Notice that defining `\NUM` with `\edef` or `\def` is exactly the same.

Answer (score 3):

In case there is some problem scheduling expansion, you can use `\expandafter` to expand macros before passing them to a `\label`:

```
\def\num{1}
\def\labeltext{{test\num}}
\expandafter\label\labeltext
\ref{test1}
```

Comment: You're missing the braces: it should be `\expandafter\label\expandafter{\labeltext}`

Comment: @egreg: Right.  It's cleaner, I think, to change the def of '\labeltext'.

Comment: Well, not in that way! :)

Comment: I've taken the liberty to edit your code.

Comment: @egreg: Ouch, right again.  I've been writing code to unescape HTML: it mangles the thought processes.

Comment: In my use case I had to use `edef` instead of `def`.